# Select date range from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a list of dates in a DF that have been converted to a YYYY-MM format and need to select a range. This is what I'm trying:

```
#create dataframe    
data = ['2016-01','2016-02','2016-09','2016-10','2016-11','2017-04','2017-05','2017-06','2017-07','2017-08']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = {'date'})

#lookup range
df[df["date"].isin(pd.date_range('2016-01', '2016-06'))]
```

It doesn't seem to be working because the date column is no longer a datetime column. The format has to be in YYYY-MM. So I guess the question is, how can I make a datetime column with YYYY-MM? Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need an actual datetime-type column or query values for this to work.  Keep it simple:

```
df[df.date.between('2016-01', '2016-06')]
```

That gives:

```
      date
0  2016-01
1  2016-02
```

It works because ISO 8601 date strings can be sorted as if they were plain strings.  '2016-06' comes after '2016-05' and so on.